# Looping tensors inside tf.GradientTape()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I need a loop to create a diffusion model - but looping inside `tf.GradientTape()` seems to create an infinite loop - where memory keeps increasing until it crashes. This is my hypothesis as I don't get any error messages.

This happens no matter how small the model is - so its not a problem with how much memory I have available.

Here is a minimal reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


class Test(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs

    def train_step(self, x0):
        steps = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            x = x0
            for step in steps:

                y = self.encoder(x, training=True)
                x = x + y

            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_sum(keras.losses.MSE(x, x0), axis=-1)

        grads = tape.gradient(reconstruction_loss, self.encoder.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.self.encoder.trainable_weights))

        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        return {"reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result()}

def main():

    epochs = 100

    # encoder
    encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    x = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(encoder_inputs)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="tanh")(x)
    y = keras.layers.Dense(1, name="z_mean")(x)
    encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, y, name="encoder")

    test = Test(encoder, name="diffusion-model")
    test.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
    test.fit(
        tf.constant(np.arange(0, 10, 1), dtype=tf.float32),
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=1,
        workers=-1,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Three step fix:

1. Use `@tf.function` decorator on top of `train_step`
2. Use `iter` in the for loop i.e.: `for step in iter(steps):`
3. Fix all the other bugs with the code